# Subtracting from a specific cell, when another specific cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a formula that will subtract column C from D, but only when Column E is empty. I've tried a few different combinations of IF, AND, OR and ISBLANK, but can't figure it out.

Formulas I've tried:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E19),"",D19-C19)
```

Resulted in the same value as a diffident column I have that is subtracting C from E.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(D19),ISNUMBER(C19)),D19-C19,"")
```

But it's not counting the first day, and trying to add one at the end would add it even if it should be 0.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(D19),ISBLANK(C19)),"",D19-C19)
```

Same issue as above it gives a value of 21, and it should be a 22. And again if I just add 1 to the end it will miss up cells that should be 0.

If it helps here is a snip of the columns

[image: ImageSnip]

Comment: Could you perhaps update the question and add the formula you've tried, and what the end result is? Please paste the formula as text, and wrap it in the curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Why the ask to wrap in curly brackets? It's not an array formula. Just format the formula as code. That's not done by typing curly brackets.

Comment: How are your formatting the result? What result do you expect when the  dates in C and D are on the same day? Your "Last contact" is always at midnight, but the "created" can be LATER on that same day??

Comment: I'm formating the results as integers. I expect a 0 to be the result if the dates are the same. The time for Last Contact can't be changed due to the nature of the program the Excel sheet is exported from, it can't be changed.

Comment: Try this: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(E19),NOT(OR(ISBLANK(D19),ISBLANK(C19),D19=C19))),D19-C19+1)`

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Harrymc answered the question with the below suggestion:

"Try this: `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(E19),NOT(OR(ISBLANK(D19),ISBLANK(C19),D19=C19))),D19-C19+1)`"